# Method with objects that implement an interface?

Tags: java

I have this exercise I want to do, but I struggle a bit with it.
It says:

> "Write a static method print which takes an array of objects whose
>   class implements Printable, and prints each element in  the array, one
>   element per line. Check it by placing it in an otherwise empty class
>   and compiling it. "

How to write a method that takes as parameter objects that implement an interface, I assume I need to use "implements Printable" but where? Can't figure it out.. I know how to do that in a class but... method?

Comment: A class that implements `Printable` is a class that is declared as implementing `Printable`. The method parameter will be an array of that type.

Comment: `void method(Printable[] objects) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your static method needs to accept an array of Printable as its argument, e.g.

```
public static void print(Printable[] printables)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the interface as a type for the array. Like this:

```
public static void print(Printable[] objectArray) {
    //All objects in objectArray implement the interface Printable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exercise requires you to perform three tasks:

1. Define an interface called `Printable` <sup>*</sup>
2. Write a static method that takes `Printable[]` as a parameter
3. Write an otherwise empty class that implements `Printable`
4. In your `main` method, create an array of `Printable`, and fill it with instances of the class defined in step 3
5. Pass the array defined in step 4 to the static method defined in step 2 to check that your code works correctly.

Here is a suggestion for an interface:

```
public interface Printable {
    void print();
}
```

Here is a suggestion for the class implementing `Printable`:

```
public class TestPrintable implements Printable {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

The static method should have a signature that looks like this:

```
public static void printAll(Printable[] data) {
    ... // Write your implementation here
}
```

The test can looks like this:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    Printable[] data = new Printable[] {
        new TestPrintable()
    ,   new TestPrintable()
    ,   new TestPrintable()
    };
    printAll(data);
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> [Java defines an interface called `Printable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html), but it serves a different purpose.